# RewriteRule includding only last part of REQUESTI_URI

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2.4, mod-proxy

```
<LocationMatch /foo/>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
 RewriteRule .* "ws://192.168.0.101:1234%{REQUEST_URI}" [P]
```

when client connects to

```
ws://www.example.com/foo/whatever_arbitrary_random
```

this works great, but the outcome is

```
ws://192.168.0.101:1234/foo/whatever_arbitrary_random
```

how can i get rid of the `/foo/` so the outcome would be

```
ws://192.168.0.101:1234/whatever_arbitrary_random
```

client must still need to connect to `/foo/` to trigger this

EDIT: I found how to do it, replace last line with

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ ws://192.168.0.101:1234/$1 [P,L]
```

But please read the first answer suggesting not to do this in a Location

Comment: "but the outcome is `ws://192.168.0.101/foo....`" - the omission of the port number is just an oversight presumably?

Comment: Hi, yes, you are correct. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use mod_rewrite directives inside `<Location>` (and `<LocationMatch>`) containers.

**UPDATE:** As stated in [the Apache docs for the `RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Although rewrite rules are syntactically permitted in `<Location>` and `<Files>` sections (including their regular expression counterparts), this should never be necessary and is unsupported. A likely feature to break in these contexts is relative substitutions.

`<Location>` sections are merged very late. When used inside a `<Location>` section, the `RewriteRule` directive matches the absolute filesystem-path, not the URL-path as would ordinarily be expected.

If `.htaccess` overrides are disabled then you can do it like this instead inside the appropriate `<Directory>` container:

```
<Directory /path/to/foo>
    # Disable .htaccess overrides if not already
    AllowOverride None

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.0.101:1234/$0 [P]
</Directory>
```

The backreference `$0` naturally excludes `/foo/`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteRule ([^/]+)/?$ ws://192.168.0.101:1234/$1 [P,L]
> ```

This only matches the last path segment, it doesn't strictly match everything after `/foo/`. This may or may not be OK, depending on your requests. eg. It will redirect a request for `/foo/bar/baz` to `/baz` only, not `/bar/baz`.

The regex should really be anchored. However, you've probably written it this way because the directive is inside a `<Location>` section and matches the absolute file-path, rather than the requested URL-path.

Incidentally, you don't need the `L` flag when used with `P` - it is implied.

---

An alternative to the above... you don't need to use these directvies in a *directory* context (ie. inside a `<Directory>` or `<Location>` section). You can instead place these rules directly in the `<VirtualHost>` container (a *virtualhost* context), in which case they should be written like this instead:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule ^/foo/(.*) ws://192.168.0.101:1234/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit more on why I shouldn't do this in a `<Location>` (and `<LocationMatch>`) ?

Comment: `$0` for me returns the document path `/var/www/html/foo/random_stuff` maybe it is because I used it inside `<LocationMatch>`?

Comment: @Tomari I've updated my answer to include more information about why mod_rewrite directives should not be used inside `<Location>` sections. I've also included an alternative when used directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container. Yes, `$0` will include the absolute filesystem path if used inside a `<Location>` section. As stated in my answer, the directive as written should be used in a `<Directory>` section, not `<Location>`. (`<LocationMatch>` is the same.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I will test this later, `L` was used because of the `?` in the regex, it was causing error `500 too many requests`. About `<Location>` is there a security risk on doing it this way or is it just the "sane" way? What is the negative impact vs the other solution? Just trying to learn as much as possible out of this opportunity :)